# Repair help. Mosfet keep shorting

Tags: mosfet, diodes, pwm, 555, cnc

I have "repaired" a cnc power nad speed control board from yoocnc (china) and it worked fine for a day. the next day the spindle just started running as power was applied. the mosfet was shorted, the pwm signal is fine.

Schematic here: https://maher-ramblings.blogspot.no/2014/08/cnc-engraver-schematics-yoocnc-nt65-3x.html

[image: Spindle drive schematic]

On this board I have shorted R3 and R4 and removed R5. R4+3 was suprisingly in the 8Kohm range and must have blown R5 and the optocoupler, but they are not in use so I just dissabled it.

Initially the ne555 also didnt work and was replaced, along with the Q1(IRF740), I didnt have a IRF740 but i put in a IRZL44 as thats what i had and it should tolerate 12vg-s.

I also cannot see the purpose for D3 diode, so any enlightenment there would also be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest somehow attaching the schematics as images here, because random blogspot pages tend to disappear, making this question completely useless if that happens in the future.

Comment: "shorted R3 and R4 and removed R5" surely that can't be the reason you operate outside the parts SOA ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R3 and R4 are from a current threshold warning. When current trough the shunt (R3+R4) rises above the threshold of U3 the controller gets a STOP signal.
For example, when the spindle is jammed.

With this circuit bypassed, you can dump the full transformer current into the spindle and FET risking damage to both.

Here are some ways you can destroy this FET:
- Slow gate. if the 555 gate drive is too slow, or not high enough, it results in the FET being in the linear region too long until it overheats.
- Back-EMF from the spindle should go through D4 and be dissipated. If D4 is open, high transients will occur and the FET will be damaged.

D3 prevents the gate voltage from going above 18Vac rectified + Vforward, if that supply is available.

The IRF740 is a 400 Vds n-channel. Yours is an IRFZ44, with **only 60V**. For a circuit running at rectified 36Vac (50Vdc) that is **very close**.
Even with D4, you'll still be looking at transients. Since diodes take a small amount of time to conduct.

This would mean you most likely have burnt it by back-EMF or gate voltage.
Vgs is not allowed to be higher or lower than 20V or 12V from ground. (in this circuit) D3 clamps the gate voltage at rectified 18V with diode drop. This will be around 25V. Beyond maximum ratings.

My suggestion would be to replace it for a >200 Vds fet with Vgs equal or better than +-20V, and protect the gate with a 15V zener diode.

Comment: Don't see how the gate voltage can exceed that 12V supply. I wonder if D3 is intended to prevent some short term failure involving the rectified 18V supply being lost, until the 12V reservoir C4 is discharged. But even that doesn't make sense. In any case, good catch on the FET voltage, and shorting out the overcurrent protection would seem like a bad idea. I'd also fit an R-C snubber across the motor in parallel with D4.

Comment: Ok, I understand what the D3 can do, and as you point out it will protect the gate from spikes over 26V (25v +0.7) but as this is over max Vgs this isn't really useful.

A 15V zener in parallell with gate-source will more effective limit the voltage there, will the D3 then be obsolete ? maybe change the value of R2.

Any of the top of your head suggestion for mosfet ? as i seem to have to order some :)

Comment: I'm inclined to toss this and connect the pwm signal directly from an arduino, as im modifying this box to work from usb and grbl anyways. I'd short the SP-SW connector and move the spindle switch to the cables instad to stop the spindle.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I like your suggestion of a RC snubber, I might fit this in, but much closer to the spindle. The over-current is not in use by anything, it only leads to 2 pins thats not connected to anything.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit description is as follows.
There is a 48V supply to a DC motor which is controlled by a MOSFET Q1. There is a flywheel diode D4 across the motor.

In series with the drain source of Q1 to the motor are 2 resistors which form part of the control circuit, Explanation below.

There are two methods of control optimised via a factory preset link. 
This can either be a PWM signal from a stepper motor board to a 555 pulse generator or via a potentiometer to control the PWM signal generated by the 555.

The 555 PWM controls the speed at which the motor is driven by the on time of the MOSFET Q1.

Jamming of the spindle motor leads the current through the MOSFET to climb rapidy, due to the motor being halted and thus the Voltage drop across the resistor pair R3 and R4 increases.
This then turns the diode of the opto-coupled (U3)on and the Emitter Collector current will increase to signal a stop condition.

A safety cut-out switch could be used in the form of a pressure sensitive switch attached directly to the travel arm of the spindle motor, or SW-SP could just be a simple on/off switch to start/stop the spindle motor.

The SP-SW forms part of the circuit as regards the supply Voltage to U1,U2(LM555) and the supply Voltage to these IC's (VR1). With this supply removed the 555 shuts down along with the opto isolator in line from the stepper motor board and the diode D3 goes to gnd, by the action of the 7812 power removal, thus forward biasing D3 and shutting off the current in Q1.

Therefore D3 forms part of the normal operation of the circuit for switching the MOSFET off, by clamping the gate of Q1 below its shut-off Voltage.

A fault condition could occur in a number of ways, however if the control circuit of the feedback loop is removed, SP-SW switch would need to be able to operate correctly for the MOSFET to survive under any condition.

I have seen mechanical sprung loaded switches which form this type of cut-out as an end stop. However as with all mechanical switches these are always prone to dirt ingress and stop working, thus the stop circuit would need to rely completely on the feedback circuit. Alternatively the SP-SW is just a start stop switch or an emergency (Big Red Button) switch.

In a fault condition once the feedback circuit was effectively removed by shorting out the two resistors (R3 + R4), the circuit would be reliant on the switch SP-SW, to turn off.
Brian has stated that the feedback circuit is not used so there is no safety cut-out for the motor, so Q1 would need to be able to withstand a constant high current. Q1 would probably also need fan assisted cooling or a large heat sink, without limiting the PWM to a set high level.

As regards the MOSFETS used, these are both enhancement types used for motor control and do have their own protection by way of a drain source body diode. This together with the flywheel diode provides ample protection against back emf.
As far as the Voltage being close, the current in the replacement mosfet is far greater than the original, so it should stand up the 50V supply Voltage easily.

As far as the gate is concerned, on both devices, it cannot climb higher or lower within 1.5V of either rail 0 or 12V. D3 has nothing to do with clamping and is to bias off the gate of Q1 on power down.

Any problems could either be a 555 timer or a motor problem.

Comment: D3 won't tie the 555 output to 27V, it will only prevent it exceeding 27V.

Comment: I can see where you are coming from, but the spindle switch is shown connecting to D3 rather than going straight to the supply. If D3 were indeed as Jeoren3 described it, you would short the 48V PSU through the motor spindle to the 25V PSU, a fault in itself. Also any PCB netlist would henerate a track tied to the SP-SW rather than the 28V line.

Comment: You've lost me. SP-SW turns the supply to VR1 on and off, it doesn't pull anything to ground. D3 helps turn off the MOSFET if the supply to VR1 is removed.

Comment: The spindle switch has two connections. It's a simple on/off switch. There's nothing on the schematic to suggest otherwise.

Comment: Fair enough but you will of course agree that the i/p Voltage will go to gnd and forward bias the diode D3 so that it shuts off Q1. I did find this useful in determining the fate of the regulator if the i/p is shorted out. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/72906/what-problems-can-arise-from-temporarily-shorting-power-supply-of-a-small-microc  See the answer by Olin Lathrop

Comment: I edited the answer in line with remarks made by Finbarr and reading of the aforementioned stack exchange article, with regards to shortin a Voltage regulator input to ground.